# .net core - Visual Studio 2015 error

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

There is a way to open .net core project in Visual Studio 2015? (I can't use 2017).
I am talking about the full version .net core (released in march). 
Currently my VS generate error: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. For .NET Core projects using `csproj` format, you need VS 2017. VS2015 just won't work.

> We are encouraging everyone doing .NET Core development to move to Visual Studio 2017, including migrating from project.json to csproj. We will not be supporting csproj and MSBuild for .NET Core in Visual Studio 2015.

[Announcing .NET Core Tools 1.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/07/announcing-net-core-tools-1-0/).